# How to know if parse database is updated in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-dashboard

I am creating a messaging app using parse

but user will know there is new message only if they exit and relaunch app.

So I wanted to know if there is any way to know if database is updated

How to do this?

Comment: Polling might work

Comment: You can use LiveQuery: https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android